# Eclipse RCP right click event

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, tableviewer

How to add right-mouse click listener on a `TableViewer` item?

Comment: Do you mean a JFace `TableViewer`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to a  JFace [`TableViewer`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Fviewers%2FTableViewer.html), you can use the following approach assuming `viewer` is your `TableViewer`.

```
MenuManager manager = new MenuManager();
viewer.getControl().setMenu(manager.createContextMenu(viewer.getControl()));

manager.add(new Action("MENU ITEM TEXT", ImageDescriptor.createFromImage(YOUR_IMAGE)) {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // get the current selection of the tableviewer
        IStructuredSelection selection = (IStructuredSelection) viewer.getSelection();
        // do something
    }
});
```

Otherwise, please clarify your question.

Comment: how to add RIGHT-mouse click listener?

Comment: @SergejPaskevic This is a right-click menu. Do you want a menu or just listen to the right click event?

Comment: @Baz just wanted to listen to the right click event, I am new to Eclipse Plugin, so this might be silly question but is there anything other then `TableViwer` by which right click could be listen.

Comment: @Vishrant To which widget do you want to add the right-click feature?

Comment: I just wanted to create a plugin that will display some `"Mouse Right Button Click"` message on mouse right click.

Comment: @Vishrant Yeah, I understand that, but **where** do you want the right mouse click to happen? Everywhere? Just on some widgets?

Comment: @Vishrant Then use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18403738/1740724) answer and add the `Menu` to every `Control` you want it to show on using [`Control#setMenu()`](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Control.html#setMenu(org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu))

Answer (score 2):

You can get the Table of the TableViewer and call

```
public void addMouseListener (MouseListener listener)
```

the [MouseEvent](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fevents%2FMouseEvent.html) will tell you which mouse-button was pressed

```
/**
 * the button that was pressed or released; 1 for the
 * first button, 2 for the second button, and 3 for the
 * third button, etc.
 */
public int button;
```