# Adding right click menu to to treeitem in SWT tree

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

How can I add a right click popup menu to a treeitem in a SWT Tree. Each treeitem should have a right click enabled on it

Comment: @dic19 I have to use only SWT.Adding a listener to a treeitem with event as SWT.MenuDetect is not working

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just use `tree.setMenu(Menu)`.

There you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Display display = Display.getDefault();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setText("StackOverflow");
    shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    final Tree tree = new Tree(shell, SWT.NONE);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        TreeItem item = new TreeItem(tree, SWT.NONE);
        item.setText("Parent " + i);

        for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            TreeItem child = new TreeItem(item, SWT.NONE);
            child.setText("Child " + i + " " + j);
        }
    }

    final Menu menu = new Menu(tree);
    tree.setMenu(menu);
    menu.addMenuListener(new MenuAdapter()
    {
        public void menuShown(MenuEvent e)
        {
            MenuItem[] items = menu.getItems();
            for (int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            {
                items[i].dispose();
            }
            MenuItem newItem = new MenuItem(menu, SWT.NONE);
            newItem.setText("Menu for " + tree.getSelection()[0].getText());
        }
    });

    shell.pack();
    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed())
    {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch())
            display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to lock the showing of the menu only for the first level of the tree? For example, to be shown only for the root.

Comment: @Justplayit94 You'd need to add a `MenuDetectListener` to the `Tree` and check the level of the item. Then set `MenuDetectEvent#doit` to `false` if you don't want the menu. Post a new question if you can't get it to work and I'll post a detailed answer.

Comment: Can you tell me how to get the level of an item of a tree though?

Comment: @Justplayit94 I guess you'll have to call `getParentItem()` on the `TreeItem` until it returns `null` and count.

Comment: And where do I have to set the `doit` attribute? Before or after the menu's listener?

Comment: @Justplayit94 Inside the `MenuDetectListener`. It's separate from the `MenuAdapter`. The `MenuDetectListener` will be called first, consequently it can prevent the menu from showing up at all by setting `e.doit = false`.

Comment: I got the concept. Thing is that I've done it like this. 

`final Menu treeMenu = new Menu(variantTree);
   
variantTree.setMenu(treeMenu);

   variantTree.addMenuDetectListener(new MenuDetectListener(){

    @Override
    public void menuDetected(MenuDetectEvent event) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     if(variantTree.getParentItem() instanceof TreeItem){
      event.doit = false;
     }else{
      event.doit = true;
     }
    }
    
   });`

It doesnt work even though I know the parent is null. Sorry, i was banned to post any questions anymore.

Comment: For the menu to enable, the parent has to be null.