# Showing a right click menu for a SWT TableItem?

Tags: java, swt

Is it possible to show a right click menu on table items with SWT? The menu would be different for every item, e.g for some rows, some of the menu items would be enabled, for others, they would be disabled. So, each row would need its own menu, and when setting up the menu i'd need a way to identify which row I was working with.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding right click menu to to treeitem in SWT tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403137/adding-right-click-menu-to-to-treeitem-in-swt-tree)

Comment: Link above works analogously for a `Table` instead of a `Tree`.

Comment: @Baz That's not really the same as what I asked here, such as being specific to the row being right clicked.

Comment: How so? Within the `Listener`, you know which row was clicked on. Just create/enable/disable the `MenuItem`s accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    table = new DynamicTable(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);        
    table.addMenuDetectListener(new MenuDetectListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void menuDetected(MenuDetectEvent e)
        {                
           int index = table.getSelectionIndex();
           if (index == -1) 
             return; //no row selected

           TableItem item = table.getItem(index);
           item.getData(); //use this to identify which row was clicked.
           //The popup can now be displayed as usual using table.toDisplay(e.x, e.y)              
        }
    });
```

More details: http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t49734.html

Comment: What's a `DynamicTable`?

Comment: @Baz I think it could be: https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/opal/wiki/DynamicTableColumns

Comment: @ClickUpvote I see, so it's completely unrelated to the question?

Comment: If he's using the same `DynamicTable`, that one works the same like the regular SWT Table

Comment: @ClickUpvote I didn't mean that the answer is unrelated, just the usage of a different table class (although almost identical).

Answer (score 6):

Listening for `SWT.MouseDown`, as suggested by @user4793956, is completely useless. The context menu is always brought up, no need to call `setVisible(true)`. Quite contrary, you need to cancel the `SWT.MenuDetect` event, if you do **not**  want the menu to pop up.

This works for me:

```
// Create context menu
Menu menuTable = new Menu(table);
table.setMenu(menuTable);

// Create menu item
MenuItem miTest = new MenuItem(menuTable, SWT.NONE);
miTest.setText("Test Item");

// Do not show menu, when no item is selected
table.addListener(SWT.MenuDetect, new Listener() {
  @Override
  public void handleEvent(Event event) {
    if (table.getSelectionCount() <= 0) {
      event.doit = false;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem of this code is, menu item "Test Item" will come for table header also.

Answer (score 2):

Without using a DynamicTable:

```
    Menu contextMenu = new Menu(table);
    table.setMenu(contextMenu);
    MenuItem mItem1 = new MenuItem(contextMenu, SWT.None);
    mItem1.setText("Menu Item Test.");

    table.addListener(SWT.MouseDown, new Listener(){

        @Override
        public void handleEvent(Event event) {
            TableItem[] selection = table.getSelection();
            if(selection.length!=0 && (event.button == 3)){
                contextMenu.setVisible(true);
            }

        }

    });
```

Comment: The code won't work, unless you declare ``contextMenu`` as ``final``.

Comment: @user1438038 unless you use Java 8