# How delete an item from SWT TreeViewer?

Tags: java, swt, jface, treeviewer

I'm working with Eclipse Standard Widget Toolkit (**SWT**), I have a TreeView object with items and an double click event (**addDoubleClickListener**) works fine, but I don't know how implement the right click for delete an item.

Answer (score 0):

1. To listen to right clicks, use [`addMenuListener`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18403137/adding-right-click-menu-to-to-treeitem-in-swt-tree). Eclipse RCP has its own more advanced mechanisms, but this should be enough for your purposes.
2. In `SelectionListener` for your `MenuItem`, remove the item from your model and refresh the viewer.